# Blocking "System.Web.HttpException: Path 'OPTIONS' is forbidden" Errors

Tags: asp.net

I am receiving this error:

```
System.Web.HttpException: Path 'OPTIONS' is forbidden
```

because of people trying to open URLs on a website from within office products.  This is well documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2920541/107062).

In order to implement:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*.xls" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
  <add verb="*" path="*.xlsx" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
</httpHandlers>
```

I need to know all the possible file extensions.  There are a lot of office file extensions and I have missed one out as I still get the error from a user agent of: Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601

Is there a way to wildcard this for a certain user agent, or is there a definitive list of file extensions somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to know the file extensions? Try a handler as such:

```
<add path="*" verb="OPTIONS, PROPFIND" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
```

As you discover additional verbs, you can add them to the verb property above.