# Ignoring OPTIONS requests

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I'm experiencing basically the same issue listed here: [Blocking "System.Web.HttpException: Path 'OPTIONS' is forbidden" Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449694/blocking-system-web-httpexception-path-options-is-forbidden-errors)

However, I'm concerned that using the StaticFileHandler will still return headers that might be useful to someone looking for vulnerabilities in our application.  Is there a way to handle this by ignoring the requests or just returning a 405 error code and nothing more?

Answer (score 0):

--

### Updated based on comments

If your just concerned with getting rid of log lines from OPTIONS requests, the below should work:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Ignore OPTIONS requests">
      <match url=".*"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="OPTIONS" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="AbortRequest" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Word of caution - while the above will do want you want, i dont think its a good idea. Sounds to me like you have an issue with how you manage/use your logs, not with what is being logged?

(Take a look at Log Parser and/or Log Parser Studio from Microsoft - its free, scriptable, and gives you a "sql-like" syntax so you can easily filter out by VERB or any other data in the log file, and it will spit out tables/graphs :).

--

### Original Post Below

Take a look at request filtering feature in iis. It allows you to either create a whitelist of allowed verbs, or just explicitly disallow specific ones. Filtering is performed early in processing a request and will return a 404.6 error

Below is the whitelist approach (allowing only GET requests, adding additional verbs as required)

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <security>
   <requestFiltering>
    <verbsallowUnlisted="false">
     <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
    </verbs>
   </requestFiltering>
  </security>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is a more generic version that allows all verbs except `OPTIONS`

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <security>
   <requestFiltering>
    <verbsallowUnlisted="true">
     <add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="false" />
    </verbs>
   </requestFiltering>
  </security>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

See Microsoft docs for request filtering by verbs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/use-request-filtering#filter-by-verbs

Comment: Won't that still produce errors when an OPTIONS request is made? We already have a rule that disallows OPTIONS requests.  The problem is that they are producing lots of errors that end up in our product's error logs and make it tedious for support to sift through when looking for real errors. We made a less than ideal fix filtering out these error in our error handling, but we'd rather have IIS just ignore these requests without creating errors.